# Microsoft band plethysmograph

Tags: sensors, microsoft-band

I am looking to get the raw green pleth signal from the band 2. I have algorithms to extract several physiological phenomena from the pleth. Documentation appears not to allow or show this. Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Which values are you trying to extract when you say the raw green pleth signal? Lung capacity? Blood volume changes?

Answer (score 0):

I can get many signals. We can not divulge exactly which signals at this time.

Comment: The Band SDK sensors streams are the rawest streams available at this time. If you need different streams then you can reach out to the team with feature requests for future Microsoft Band SDK versions at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will do that. Regards, Don